# Lodash union of arrays of mongoose ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongoose, union, lodash

I have 2 arrays that containing ObjectId items: `array1` `array2`

I want to create a union between those 2 arrays. for that i'm running:

```
let res = _.union(array1, array2);
```

But `res` contains duplicates ObjectId.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at two different arrays with strings of 'objectIDs' you can use `concat` and then `uniq` to remove the duplicates. Don't forget to run `valueOf` at the end of your Lodash chain to call it to execute.

Below is an illustrative example:

```js
let array1 = ['42142141221421d', '9999'];

let array2 = ['s421421412412fef3', '42142141221421d', '1234'];

const res = _(array1)
       .concat(array2)
       .uniq()
       .valueOf();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: my arrays don't have objects in them, but only ObjectIds.
example: array1 = ["s421421412412fef3", "42142141221421d"].

this is the only field in it

Comment: Sorry for the delay @YoniMayer . Check out the new answer above; it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using _.uniqBy(res, 'ObjectId'); That should remove duplicate objectId in your new res array

```
let newRes = _.uniqBy(res, 'ObjectId');
```